# Recursive view VueJS3

Tags: vuejs3

I created a Comment.vue component to represent common comment hierarchical view where we can have replied to comments displayed the same than the parent comment (very common like on reddit)

```
<template>
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment_header">
            <div>{{ comment_data.user }} - {{ comment_data.relativetime }}</div>
        </div>      
        <div class="content">{{ comment_data.content }}</div>

        <div class="comment" v-for="comment_item in comment_data.replies">
            <CommentComponent :comment_data='comment_item'></CommentComponent>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CommentComponent from '@/components/Comment.vue'

export default {
    props: ['comment_data'],
    mounted() {
    },
    components: { CommentComponent }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Here is the content of comment_data

```
{ id: "1_" + i, post_id: "NewsOfToday", user: "user1", 
  content: "Often recommended but i haven't watched enough to have opinion: ICT, Thomas Wade, Mack's price action, Al brooks' books.", timestamp: 1686710191, score: 10, 
replies: [ { id: "2_" + i, post_id: "NewsOfToday", user: "user2", content: "Mostly the same principles apply as stocks. The CME has some videos that explain how futures work differently.", timestamp: 1686710191, score: 10 } ] 
}
```

When rendered in Firefox I have the following error :
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'CommentComponent' before initialization

I expected to have no errors

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import the file into itself, that won't work. But [SFCs can refer to themselves by their filename](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#recursive-components) . So you can just remove the import statement and use `<Comment>` instead of `<CommentComponent>`.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLl1zaBNRbFCoB6gEOgAo3zCFKNq2LY1t+hEhR/p212wQqUE+2Z2bt2R0P9FbrtPNAc1rYynDtiAXn9ZpJ3mplHNlCRRqjWpKkGe6DOGGyyI5q1OHBQatF6QBPhBShogbt9jeMrhjNEC2yWUIX1NlKyYbv0oNVEl8eQhmjlWo1F2CeteNKWkZzEpnAlUKor8eIOeNhMeHVHqrPf/CD7QPG6IsBC6YDRmfOlWYH7khvXp+gx/1Mtqr2AtUXyC1YJXzweJTdeVmj7V+66PYhzo/L3Zvd9A6knZoKRoNyjHpGcaL3F1r/sbtKV7GOyRGneAojJHc2f0yg5t06pDAMMYdxLLIAndjAdEveYDyRJmtyxSjJp8ziurz+k1yMeo4d+vg9amhKL9xkVxulbU7ek3hJ8oEtot2z/0LHb50j0AE=).

---

Alternatively, if you set a [name](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#name) for the component, you can use that:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CommentComponent',
  ...
}
</script>
```

Here is another [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstOwzAQ/BXLl1xoAuotCpUA9QBCgAo3zCFKNq1L/JAfIVKUf2ftNoEK1FPsmdns7I4HeqN12nmgOS1sZbh2xILzesUkF1oZRzZQkcYoQZI0w3MQJ0wW2UGNOrw4ELotHeCNkCJU1KDd7prRJaMZokU2S+gFdbZSsuHbdG+VxM5DKGO0UkLzFsyzdlxJy2hOIhO4sm3V10PEnPFwMeHVDqrPf/C97QPG6IsBC6YDRmfOlWYL7kCvX5+gx/NMClX7FtVnyA1Y1frg8SC79bJG27900e193B+X2ze77h1IOw0VjAblGPWM4kbvzoz+Y3eZLmMdkyNu8RhGSO5k/5hAzbtVSGEYYg7jWGQBOrKPoZ0A6Ui34A2GFEVkRS4ZJfmUXPwurv7kFwOfw4c+PpIamtK3bjKtjdI2J+9J/EnycVyMLAXkJJn7J4jjMCeviY7foN3Zrg==)

Comment: That's great! If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted answer and/or upvote it. It's a bit silly, but it is how the site works